# GSA 7.4 default_frontend and suggest and user-added results

Tags: google-search-appliance

The team that is in charge of GSA in my company seem to accidentally overwrite our collections and frontends where we have 4 of each now I am new developer for the application that utilize GSA search and I have been told that the search functionality was working fine in the beginning of this year but what surprise me is the following inside the code we are using the following call for GSA:

```
http://go-yyy/suggest?token=as&access=p&client=yyy_frontend&output=xml_no_dtd&proxystylesheet=yyy_frontend&sort=date:D:L:d1&oe=UTF-8&ie=UTF-8&ud=1&exclude_apps=1&site=yyy-coll
```

and it use to return the term is non-empty and the content and the URL also not empty.

But going back to the documentation of GSA 7.4 they stated the following

The client distinguishes between suggest and user-added results as follows:

> - For suggest results, the term is non-empty while the content and the URL are empty.
> - For user-added results, the term is empty, content is optional, and the URL is non-empty. A client can choose to display both suggest and user-added results or just one of them. The default front end provided in the Admin Console’s XSLT stylesheet, displays both results. User-added results display after suggest results and appear in italics.

So my question where and how CAN I choose to display both suggest and user-added results?

Do we really have to create a create a new user result configuration to receive the term, content and URL? If this has to be done how can make sure that we are not skipping the suggested result?

Comment: Taking a wild guess your question is related to Google Search Appliance (so I tagged it as such). Otherwise it doesn't make much sense at all (notice that you  never named the product you're using, within your question).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the user-added results are adding value in your context?